# What is the syntax error in helloworld.s main line

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm new to Assembly and Qtspim. 
When trying to load the helloworld.s program, I get a syntax error:

`spim: (parser) syntax error on line 8 of file helloworld.s 
main:   li $v0,`

This is the code I'm using:

```
        .data
msg:   .asciiz "Hello World"
    .extern foobar 4

        .text
        .globl main

main:   li $v0, 4       
        la $a0, msg     
        syscall         
        lw $t1, foobar

        jr $ra
```

BTW - I'm using the Mac version of QtSpim 9.1.20.

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe the assembler doesn't like a label and code in the same line. To test this, insert a linebreak between the label and the code, right after the colon.

Comment: Does the actual error message really end after the comma on that line, omitting the `4` at the end?  If so, that would indicate that an unprintable character somehow got inserted in the line just before the `4`, and the assembler is choking on it.

Comment: The problem was actually in settings. "Use Bare Machine" was selected for some reason.